# Python subprocess.run not accepting /D argument for makensis.exe

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I have a NSIS script that accepts an argument ${appname} and creates an installer based on the given name, the nsis script is called from a python script, which also does other stuff. This is the code I am using for calling the NSIS script

```
def run_nsis_process(self,product_name,script, logger):
    NSIS_PATH='C:/Program Files (x86)/NSIS'    
    try:                            
        nsis_args = '/Dappname='+product_name+ ' '+ script                          
        process_completed = subprocess.run(['makensis.exe', nsis_args], shell=True, cwd = NSIS_PATH, universal_newlines = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, check=True)                              
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        logger.error('The makensis.exe subprocess existed with the following code {} \n The makensis.exe produced the following error text{}'.format(err.returncode, err.output))        
    else:                         
        logger.info('Output from NSIS:\n{}'.format(process_completed.stdout))
```

This gives me an error that I am not using the correct makensis.exe arguments. Just for information the */Dappname=value* accepts the value and sends it to the makensis script as an argument to the nsis script. The error I get is

```
The makensis.exe produced the following error textCommand line defined: "appname=EDMsdk O:\dev/product/NSIS/installer.nsi"
```

If I replace the subprocess.run with os.system as so

```
def run_nsis_process(self,product_name,script, logger):
    NSIS_PATH='C:/Program Files (x86)/NSIS'    
    try:                            
        nsis_args = '/Dappname='+product_name+ ' '+ script              
        nsis_cmd = 'makensis.exe /Dappname='+product_name+ ' '+ script                                
        #process_completed = subprocess.run(['makensis.exe', nsis_args], shell=True, cwd = NSIS_PATH, universal_newlines = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, check=True)                              
        os.system(nsis_cmd)            
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        logger.error('The makensis.exe subprocess existed with the following code {} \n The makensis.exe produced the following error text{}'.format(err.returncode, err.output))        
    else:                         
        logger.info('Output from NSIS:\n{}'.format(process_completed.stdout))
```

than everything works and I get the installer executable.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here, any suggestions

cheers,

es

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one

```
def run_nsis_process(self,product_name,script, logger):
    NSIS_PATH='C:/Program Files (x86)/NSIS'    
    try:                            
        nsis_args = ['/Dappname=', product_name, script]                          
        process_completed = subprocess.run(['makensis.exe'] + nsis_args, shell=True, cwd = NSIS_PATH, universal_newlines = True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, check=True)                              
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        logger.error('The makensis.exe subprocess existed with the following code {} \n The makensis.exe produced the following error text{}'.format(err.returncode, err.output))        
    else:                         
        logger.info('Output from NSIS:\n{}'.format(process_completed.stdout))
```

The problem is that you passed one argument

Comment: Thanks, did one small fix, nsis_args = ['/Dappname='+ product_name, script] and it worked,  The previous  one was looking for a script with product_name as a name. Thanks again